# Not able to get response in viewModel from repo while using NetworkboundResource class in kotlin android using coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to fetch records from retrofit using NetworkBoundResource but not able to get a response. Actually when I did debug it did not go through all functions in Repository. Here my code for all classes

**NetWorkBoundResource**

```
abstract class NetworkBoundResource<ResponseObject, ViewStateType> {

protected val result = MediatorLiveData<DataState<ViewStateType>>()

init {
    result.value = DataState.loading(true)


    GlobalScope.launch(IO){
        delay(TESTING_NETWORK_DELAY)

        withContext(Main){
            val apiResponse = createCall()
            result.addSource(apiResponse) { response ->
                result.removeSource(apiResponse)

                handleNetworkCall(response)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun handleNetworkCall(response: GenericApiResponse<ResponseObject>){

    when(response){
        is ApiSuccessResponse ->{
            handleApiSuccessResponse(response)
        }
        is ApiErrorResponse ->{
            println("DEBUG: NetworkBoundResource: ${response.errorMessage}")
            onReturnError(response.errorMessage)
        }
        is ApiEmptyResponse ->{
            println("DEBUG: NetworkBoundResource: Request returned NOTHING (HTTP 204)")
            onReturnError("HTTP 204. Returned NOTHING.")
        }
    }
}

fun onReturnError(message: String){
    result.value = DataState.error(message)
}

abstract fun handleApiSuccessResponse(response: ApiSuccessResponse<ResponseObject>)

abstract fun createCall(): LiveData<GenericApiResponse<ResponseObject>>

fun asLiveData() = result as LiveData<DataState<ViewStateType>>}
```

**Repository**

```
object Repository {
private const val TAG = "Repository"
fun getBlogPosts(): LiveData<DataState<List<BlogPost>>> {
    return object: NetworkBoundResource<List<BlogPost>, List<BlogPost>>(){

        override fun handleApiSuccessResponse(response: ApiSuccessResponse<List<BlogPost>>) {
            result.value = DataState.data(
                null,
                    data = response.body
            )
        }

        override fun createCall(): LiveData<GenericApiResponse<List<BlogPost>>> {
            return MyRetrofitBuilder.apiService.getBlogPosts()
        }

    }.asLiveData()
}

suspend fun getUser(userId: String): LiveData<DataState<User>> {
    return object: NetworkBoundResource<User, User>(){

        override fun handleApiSuccessResponse(response: ApiSuccessResponse<User>) {
            result.value = DataState.data(
                null,
                    data = response.body
                )
        }

        override fun createCall(): LiveData<GenericApiResponse<User>> {
            return MyRetrofitBuilder.apiService.getUser(userId)
        }

    }.asLiveData()
}}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val TAG = "MainViewModel"
private val mediatorBlog: MediatorLiveData<List<BlogPost>> = MediatorLiveData()
private val mediatorUser: MediatorLiveData<User> = MediatorLiveData()
private val _blogPost: MutableLiveData<DataState<List<BlogPost>>> = MutableLiveData()
val blogPost: LiveData<DataState<List<BlogPost>>>
    get() = _blogPost
private val _user: MutableLiveData<User> = MutableLiveData()
val user: LiveData<User>
    get() = _user



fun getBlogPosts(){
        val list = Repository.getBlogPosts()
        Log.d(TAG, "List: $list")
        mediatorBlog.addSource(list, Observer {list ->
            _blogPost.value = list
        })
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    viewModel = this.run {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    }

    subscribeObservers()

}

private fun subscribeObservers() {

    viewModel.getBlogPosts()

    viewModel.blogPost.observe(this, Observer {blogPost ->
        tv_response.text = blogPost.toString()
    })
}}
```

That's all I am not getting an error or any warning even use try-catch block.